# control width of event bar in FullCalendar resourceTimeline view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, gantt-chart

I am using FullCalendar v6. I am showing 6 months data in Calendar and each slot is of 1 month.I am creating the event of 10 days and it's taking the whole month slot's width but I want that if event is of 10days then the event bar should take 1/3 width of the month slot's width. Below is my code:

```
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[
          interactionPlugin,
          resourceTimelinePlugin,
          dayGridPlugin,
          multiMonthPlugin,
          scrollgridPlugin,
          timelinePlugin,
        ]}
        eventMinWidth={5}
        initialView='sixMonthView'
        daym
        views={
          {
            sixMonthView: {
              eventOverlap: false,
              type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
              duration: { months: 12},
              slotLabelInterval: {months: 1},
              slotDuration: { days: 1 },
              dateIncrement: { months: 6 },
              slotLabelClassNames: 'slot-label',
              slotMinWidth: 120,
              // slotLabelContent: slotLabelContentForOneMonth,
            },

          }
        }
        editable={true}
        selectable={true}
        selectMirror={true}
        dayMaxEvents={true}
        weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
        resources={[
          { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
          { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
          { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
        ]}
        // firstDay={6}
        initialDate={'2023-07-01'}
        initialEvents={[
          { title: 'nice', start: '2023-08-01', end: '2023-08-10', resourceId: 'a', allDay: true },
        ]}
      />
```

Current result is :

[image]

My expected result should be :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using React as your framework.

In my opinion, you should set up a new CSS class and give events that you want to be half-width or idk how much width you want that class name.

First, inspect your target element and set up a CSS class (fc-event-xyz). You might need to use important to overwrite some styles.

Next there is a prop in the FullCalendar called:

```
eventClassNames={e => singleEventClassNameHandler(e)}
```

where **e** is the  *EventContentArg* (basically an event with all the necessary info that the event has). I can't write the whole logic for you but basically, you can set up dynamic classes settings based on the duration of the events that you receive from the **e**
argument.

Comment: what I need to return from singleEventClassNameHandler

Comment: A string or an array of strings